# Meaning of "网络驿站"

Tags: translation, slang

I've come across the phrase "网络驿站" a couple of times recently, but don't understand precisely what it means (see [Hbjjrb.com](http://www.hbjjrb.com/yaowen/yw/201301/583647.html) for an example).

The only translation of 驿站 that I can find refers to a relay station for post horses, and it seems like it's sometimes used in place names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

网络驿站 is only a fancy name that can be used to name a link on someone's personal webpage or the web site itself, such as 知心姐姐网络驿站. It has only the naming function, but not a jargon at all.

As for 驿站, a simple definition from baidu.com

```
驿站是国家出现以后，政府专门为传递公文和军情所设置的通信机构，至今已有3000年历史。
```

Translation: For 3000 years since the advent of sovereign states, 驿站 Yizhan has been the communications network used by the government for delivering official documents and military intelligence.

Comment: Interestingly, 驛 (역 YŎK) in modern Korea(n) means (metro) station, the equivalent of Chinese 站...